# Issue with usercontrol BorderStyle

Tags: .net, user-controls

I have created a user control (custom DataGridView control). I have used the example in [this MSDN article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316574) to set the border style.

I am able to see the selected border style in designer. Like None, FixedSingle or Fixed3D.

But when I set the border style to FixedSingle, the border does not appear at runtime. Do I need to draw it manually in the OnPaint method?

If I use following code

```
private BorderStyle borderStyle = BorderStyle.None;

      [Browsable (true)]
      public new BorderStyle BorderStyle
      {
         get
         {
            return borderStyle;
         }

         set
         {
            if (borderStyle != value)
            {
               if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(BorderStyle), value))
               {
                  throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException("value", (int)value, typeof(BorderStyle));
               }

               base.BorderStyle = value;
               UpdateStyles();
            }
         }
      }
```

The border on designer but its size is fixed, its smaller than the grid size. Its size remain same even if I resize grid and the same border appears in runtime.

Answer (score 1):

That KB article is badly outdated, it talks about .NET 1.x.  In .NET 2.0, UserControl got a BorderStyle property.  It can be set to None, FixedSingle and Fixed3D.  FixedSingle works fine when I try it, I never heard of a problem with it.  Remove the CreateParams override.

---

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class MyDgv : DataGridView {
  public MyDgv() {
    base.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
  }

  [Browsable(true)]
  [DefaultValue(BorderStyle.None)]
  public new BorderStyle BorderStyle {
    get { return base.BorderStyle; }
    set {
      if (base.BorderStyle != value) {
        base.BorderStyle = value;
        UpdateStyles();
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: If I remove the CreateParams  override, the border does not get applied in design time as well.

Comment: So, did you actually change the BorderStyle property in the designer?

Comment: No, I have not override it. I am deriving my control from system grid control. But I am doing lots of things in paint.

Comment: Erm, this doesn't have anything to do with UserControl then?  DataGridView also has a BorderStyle property.  What happened to it?  What is the actual base class of your control?

Comment: DataGridView has a BorderStyle property.  Why doesn't it work?  Are you overriding it and not setting the base.BorderStyle property?  Time to post some code, I have no idea what you are doing.

Comment: Please check the problem statement again. I have added the code there.

Comment: There's a bug in your setter, it doesn't update the "borderStyle" member.  I updated my post with another version.